# Help with Connecting a Japanese Toilet (Bidet) to US toilet and plumbing line

Tags: plumbing, toilet, hose

My first post on this board and looking for help. I've really been struggling to get this thing installed.

Forewarning: I know little to nothing about plumbing, so excuse my incorrect use of terminology and lack of knowledge.

My problem is that the t-connector to add the hose to the Japanese toilet seat is a 1/2" connector and my toilet takes a 7/8" BC to 3/8" C to the wall.

So first, I tried buying a bunch of connectors/adapters from Home depot to convert the Japanese Toto T - connector from 1/2" to 3/8" on both ends and then connect it onto the tap coming out of the wall. For some reason all the seals would just leak all over the place. No idea why this was happening.

So instead, I decided to just buy a US 1/2" Bidet T-connector. This way I can just install this in-line with the US hose (the 7/8" to 3/8" 12inch hose) and then connect the Japanese Toto T-connector to the one end of it.

However, to do this, I now need to cap off (close) the 3 end of the Japanese Toto T-connector with the other end successfully connected to the hose to the Japanese Toto hose. The reason for this is, I MUST use the Toto T-connector, because I found that the threaded end on the Toto connector is specialized to have an edge on the tip of the threaded end to create the seal with the Toto hose to the bidet. So it won't seal if connected to the 1/2" end of the US Bidet T-connector. Incredibly annoying, as I found out after connecting and thinking I was done, instead having water spray everywhere.

Okay, so hopefully you are still reading. I think I have a solution with the above, but here is my (hopefully) final question. The end cap that I bought does not seem to completely screw on. I have included pictures. Is this normal? For example, you can see the 1/2" compression connector screws on just fine and fits snug. However the End Caps won't screw completely on. Is this normal for endcaps, that's what the home depot guy said, but I have concerns.

I have two photos of two different 1/2" caps. You can see from the photos, one of them probably screws on about 2-3 threads and then gets snug. The other one barely holds onto one thread of the connector. The second one almost feels like the threads are not even the same.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Update: well, I failed again. Both the 1/2" cap and using the 1/2" compression connector with attached 3/8" cap leaked when I turned on the water. I'm a bit at a loss. I guess the only option I have is to contact Toto to see if they have a US adapter piece. Luckily it seems with the spacers they provided me, the connection between the Toto T-connector and the US Bidet connector keeps the seal and does not leak. It's just the side that I want to cap off now. I guess I need to buy the darn cap from Toto. Ugh. This is such a painful process, which I would have assumed would be easy.

Comment: So you were able to make the connections with the adapters that you bought but they leaked,  correct?  Did you use any type of thread sealant on the threads -  either Teflon tape or pipe dope,  typically Teflon tape would be used except for on compression fittings.  Threads will make the connections but they won’t create a watertight seal without some form of thread sealant.  Also if you could post the model number of the toilet or a link to its spec sheet it would be helpful for us to see what kind of connection it requires.